# SubQuery in Django 1.11.8 is very slow - can I speed it up?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have some tables that aren't joined by a FK relationship in two separate Django models and I'm trying to do a `SubQuery`. Data looks like this:

```
# "master" data table - reflects real property ownership by humans
# there are often changes to property ownership
class OwnershipRecord(Model):
  parcel = CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
  owner_name = ...
  other data fields ...

# Poor man's 'elastic search' or an index of sorts for OwnershipRecord
class Lead(Model):
  ownership_record = OneToOneField(OwnershipRecord)
  preforeclosure = BooleanField(default=False)
  aggregated data/booleans/etc...

# "descriptor" table for a property
# there are not often changes to a property's physical traits
ResidentialMasterRecord(Model):
  parcel = CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)  # These are the SAME as OwnershipRecord
  livablesqft = ...
  lotsqft = ...
```

So I'm working on a query that can filter `Lead` objects by square footage. The `Lead` is related to the `OwnershipRecord`, but there are no relationships to `ResidentialMasterRecord` - it exists as a "fact table" kind of like a set of coordinates would for a specific address.

I thought a `SubQuery` would work in this case, where I can reference the `parcel` from the `OwnershipRecord` and `ResidentialMasterRecord` to link the two real-time.

This is **extremely** slow. Here is the query I'm attempting:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, SubQuery
from myapp.models import OwnershipRecord, Lead, ResidentialMasterRecord

RMR_SQ = ResidentialMasterRecord.objects \
           .filter(parcel=OuterRef("ownership_record__parcel"))
qs = Lead.objects.select_related('ownership_record') \
         .annotate(sqft=SubQuery(RMR_SQ.values("livablesqft")[:1])) \
         .filter(sqft__gte=1500)
```

I'm looking at query times in the range of 15-45 minutes - but I DO eventually get results... **Any ideas on how to speed this thing up while maintaining a non-foreignkey-linked structure?**

---

Django 1.11.8
PostgreSQL 9.5
Droplet w/ 8GB RAM, 4 cores

Comment: How many records are we talking here? Preferably for each table/model. Can you also include all the fields in each model? It might help paint a better picture (for me anyway).

Comment: Are the Foreign Key columns indexed? If you have access to the Postgresql logs, can you extract the full query that is getting executed, run it with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) your_query` and paste it into https://explain.depesz.com/ to easily see where the slowdowns might be coming from.

Comment: OwnershipRecord = 2M // Lead = 300K // ResidentialMasterRecord=1.4M

Comment: @bma I don't know if they are indexed, honestly. I've never made a specific effort to index them, if that means anything. I have full access to the Droplet, so I can likely figure out the `EXPLAIN` thing.

Comment: FK columns should always be indexed, otherwise you're going to get full-table scan instead of index scans. On tiny tables this is fine, but in your case you'll see some benefit if they aren't already indexed. Note that the FK columns are not indexed on the child side by default, but the parent side will have an index (automatically created by the Primary Key or Unique constraint).

Comment: @wholevinski I can't post the whole models - my post is "mostly code" and I can't hit the post button. Each model is around 40 fields. OwnershipRecord and ResidentialMasterRecord are imported directly from outside files. Lead model was created by me to index the 12 other models that are attached by FK to OwnershipRecord.

Comment: @PANDAStack That's fine. I re-read it and I see the important pieces right now. I wanted to keep a "sheer volume of data" option open, but that's obviously not what's going on. bma's suggestion about indexing the FK column is most likely the right path.

Comment: and also, you can add indexes on other columns too.  Oftentimes, the first question I have when anyone asks about slow db queries is "Do you have any indexes built on the table?" and the answer is often no or I don't know.

Comment: @bma @wholevinski From the docs: A database index is automatically created on the ForeignKey. -- Perhaps I need to also index `parcel` field. I will do so.

Comment: @PANDAStack I could be wrong, but I'm not sure the parcel one is the issue. I'm seeing the  `sqft=RMR_SQ.values("livablesqft")[:1]` being the issue. Indexing `Lead.sqft` was what I was thinking. That statement essentially translates to a giant `IN` operator against what I'm assuming are a lot of sqft values. Indexing `sqft` should lessen that time it takes for that.

Comment: @wholevinski There is no `sqft` field on `Lead` - so I am trying to get one temporarily by `annotate`. If it comes down to it, I created `Lead` to help me with this problem so I can make and fill that field on all current and existing 300K model instances.

Comment: Answer posted - thanks to you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is a result of inspiration from the comments by @bma and @wholevinski.

As stated in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey),

> A database index is automatically created on the ForeignKey.

**The key to this subquery problem is to index** on the `JOIN` fields (aka: `parcel` in the case of my question). That is simple, and it looks like this:

```
class OwnershipRecord(Model):
  parcel = CharField(max_length=10, unique=True,
                     db_index=True)
  owner_name = ...
  other data fields ...

ResidentialMasterRecord(Model):
  parcel = CharField(max_length=10, unique=True,
                     db_index=True)
  livablesqft = ...
  lotsqft = ...
```

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#db-index) for this are sparse, but easy enough to implement.

> **db_index**
>
> *Field.db_index*
>
> If **True**, a database index will be created for this field.

**Results**: My query went from ~30 minutes to 1.55 seconds.

---

```
>>> import timeit
>>> from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
>>> from leads.models import Lead
>>> from ownership.models import OwnershipRecord
>>> from mcassessor.models import ResidentialMasterRecord
>>> rmr_sq = ResidentialMasterRecord.objects.filter(parcelid=OuterRef('ownership_record__parcel'))
>>> qs = Lead.objects.select_related('ownership_record').annotate(sqft=Subquery(rmr_sq.values("livablesqft")[:1])).filter(sqft__gte=1700)
>>> toc = timeit.default_timer()
... qs_list = list(qs)
... print(timeit.default_timer() - toc)
[Out] 1.55457401276
>>> len(qs_list)
[Out] 823
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) even though the underlying database does not have an fkey relationship, you can specify that two tables are related in the ORM.
(2) Like @bma mentioned, indexing will make a big difference with performance.

But, here, in general is my strategy--break up your subquery into two separate queries and keep some data in-memory.

e.g.,

```
def chunkify(rg, chunk_size=1000):
    while rg:
        yield rg[:chunk_size]
        rg = rg[chunk_size:]

min_sq_footage = 1500
master_records = ResidentialMasterRecords.objects.filter(sqft__gte=min_sq_footage)
parcels = list(master_records.values_list('parcel', flat=True))
for parcel_chunk in chunkify(parcels):
    qs = Lead.objects.select_related('ownership_record').filter(ownership_record__parcel__in=parcel_chunk)
    # do some work
```

Comment: I love this answer - and I use this technique **almost all** the time. In this case, I struggle to implement it. *Here's why:* this subquery problem is part of a 20-input filtering form, where the results are fetched/returned using AJAX. So I am chaining filters dynamically depending on the user inputs on the frontside. Number of results requested/available range from 10 - 200,000. One way to implement would be streaming AJAX response a la infinite scroll. That's a bridge too far for now.